# Getting custom field value to functions.php and displaying in on the shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields, wordpress-shortcode

Maybe someone would be able to help me with the issue I have as I'm stuck with no ideas.

I have a shortcode on my site that is responsible for displaying photosets directly from Flickr (via external plugin).

The code generated by the plugin is the following:
[justified_image_grid preset=c1 flickr_user=USERID flickr_photoset=PHOTOSETID]

My blog posts displays various photosets from Flickr. I'd like to avoid having to edit shortcode each and every time to update the shortcode code with the proper photoset ID so I decided to use custom field (Key = FlicktPhotoset, Value = Photoset ID) and add function to functions.php that would create my shortcode which would include original shortcode with the value from custom field.

Code in functions.php is the following:

```
function flickr_shortcode() {
    echo do_shortcode('[justified_image_grid preset=c1 flickr_user=USERNAME flickr_photoset=PHOTOID]');
}
function flickr_shortcodes_init() {
    add_shortcode('flickr', 'flickr_shortcode');
}
add_action('init', 'flickr_shortcodes_init');
```

What I'm stuck at is how to pass shortcode value into this code to automatically fetch PHOTOID from the custom field value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
function flickr_shortcode() {
    $FlicktPhotoset = get_post_custom_values("FlicktPhotoset");       
    echo do_shortcode('[justified_image_grid preset=c1 flickr_user=USERNAME flickr_photoset='.$FlicktPhotoset[0].']');
}
function flickr_shortcodes_init() {
    add_shortcode('flickr', 'flickr_shortcode');
}
add_action('init', 'flickr_shortcodes_init');
```

Comment: Nope, unfortunately something like this doesn't work. While I'm using this code, Flickr API returns information that the photoset of this ID doesn't exist. When I replace it with ID number (without getting custom field value) it's working fine. It seems to me that somehow Function cannot get the custom field value.

Comment: Sorry, I think this function return array, I modified code, try new one, please. Also, it's depends where you run your shortcode, if you use it outside of loop — you also have to pass post_ID as second parameter.

Comment: Great. Many thanks. It worked just the way I wanted. I really appreciate your help